# Mongoose update not updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update a document which has a specific ID with the current date/time but the below code is not resulting in the DB getting updated and no errors. Any help would be great, thanks.

Schema:

```
var MerchantShema = new Schema({
    merchant_id: Number,
    merchant_aw_id: Number,
    merchant_name: String,
    merchant_url: String,
    merchant_image: String,
    product_feed: String,
    product_feed_updated: Date,
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

Update Query:

```
updateMerchantLastProductUpdate: function (mID) {
  now = new Date();      

  var query = { "merchant_aw_id" : mID };
  Merchants.update(query, { "product_feed_updated": now }, function (err) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);        
  })
}
```

Route

```
  app.get('/queries', function (req, res) {
    queries.updateMerchantLastProductUpdate("2926");
  });
```

Example document

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55997638e4b01f0391cb99aa"
    },
    "merchant_id": "0003",
    "merchant_aw_id": "2926",
    "merchant_name": "Multipower",
    "merchant_url": "www.multipower.com/uk/",
    "merchant_image": "",
    "product_feed": "aw",
    "product_feed_updated": "",
    "created_at": "",
    "updated_at": ""
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `merchant_aw_id` field in your mongoose schema is expecting a number so you need to parse the string for integer by using the **[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** method in your query. You also need the **[`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)** update operator which replaces the value of a field with the specified value to update your document, together with the `{multi: true}` option which if set to true, updates multiple documents that meet the query criteria. If set to false, updates one document. The default value is false:

```
updateMerchantLastProductUpdate: function (mID) {
    var now = new Date(),
        query = { "merchant_aw_id" : parseInt(mID) },
        update = {
            "$set": { "product_feed_updated": now } 
        },
        options = { "multi": true };

    Merchants.update(query, update, options, function (err) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);         
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks but just tried this and I have the same issue. DB not updating/no error

Answer (score 1):

My error was caused by my model have the ID I was looking for in the format Number but my data in mongoDB was a String